# How to use ActiveRecord none method properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my controller:

```
@registrations = Registration.where('id > 1000000000')
Event.unarchived.each do |event|
  event.registrations.by_submitted.each do |reg|
    @registrations << reg
  end
end
```

There has to be a better way to do this.  I've tried replacing the first line with:

```
@registrations = Registration.none
```

But when I do that, the final `@registrations` variable always comes up with zero records.

What is the proper way to use the `none` method here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to do it this way:

```
registration_ids = []
Event.unarchived.each do |event|
  registration_ids << event.registrations.by_submitted.pluck(:id)
end
@registrations = Registration.where(id: registration_ids.flatten)
```